# MySQL SUM(costs) WHERE id = X

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select the SUM of a row where the ID matches a php integer.

It's turning the SUM of all my costs, not costs specific to the ID.

```
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(myTable.myCostAmount) 
                    AS total, myOthertable.myOthertableID 
                    FROM myOthertable, myTable WHERE myOthertable.myOthertableID = '$myInt'");
```

So I am trying to select the ID from myOtherTable, and return the SUM of myCostamount from myTable. Do I need to use some sort of JOIN here, as the SELECT doesnt seem to be working with the WHERE.

I've thought about using a foreach to avoid this confusion, I just want to SUM the outputted results where the ID = X. (Stored in $myInt).

Comment: Hm... myothertable reads as 'mother table' at first glance. I know it's spam, but I couldn't resist :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  SUM(myTable.myCostAmount) AS total,
  myOthertable.myOthertableID 
FROM 
  myOthertable
  INNER JOIN myTable ON myOtherTable.CommonField=myTable.CommonField
WHERE
  myOthertable.myOthertableID = '$myInt'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are already using a join, as `FROM myOthertable, myTable` in your SQL is an implicit join.

What you need, though, is an explicit join, stating how the tables should be joined. Further, you need a `GROUP BY`, because otherwise an aggregate function makes no sense.

Without knowing your table structure or relation, I cannot give an exact answer, but it would be along the lines of:

```
SELECT SUM(myTable.myCostAmount) AS total, myOthertable.myOthertableID 
FROM myOthertable
LEFT JOIN myTable ON myTable.myOtherTableID = myOthertable.myOtherTableID
WHERE myOthertable.myOthertableID = '$myInt'
GROUP BY myTable.myOtherTableID
```

If you include your table structure (at least for the relevant columns), along with information how they are related, I can edit my response to a more exact solution.

Comment: Seems logical, i'll give it a go :)

Comment: And if you want more information on joins, take a look at this blogpost http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score -1):

I've used PHP for this.

```
$grandTotal += $total;
```

Comment: by doing this on php side you are adding cost of transmitting whole set of unneeded data from db to php.

Comment: I've taken the DB out of the equation and used a previous SQL statement to achieve the above. Thanks for your input, though.

Comment: sry, I totally misunderstood that you are answering your own question.